# if $\alpha\leq\beta$ then there is $\gamma$ such as $\alpha+\gamma=\beta$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to prove the statement in the title, a.e existence of ordinal substraction.
I think it can be done with transfinite induction, but do any of you have a better/easier way?

thanks

Comment: See you tomorrow!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Just for my feeling, was it wrong/forbidden to ask this in the internet? I thought it would be good to see other ways (it was obvious to me that mine, induction, isn't the correct) and it simply educates me.

Comment: No no, it's more than fine! I'm happy to see my students study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider the unique $\gamma$ isomorphic to $\beta\setminus\alpha$.